# Viewing IIS logs on the console

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is there a way to view IIS logs the way I can view iisexpres.exe logs? I mean real time, on the console?
The most important part of the question is of course 'realtime', because IIS caches log contents and flushes it periodically.

m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on specifically what are you trying to achieve, if it is for development purposes or more proudction use. There is no easy way to look at "logs" specifically in real time. However, I can think of a couple of options:

1. You could use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) to parse the logs in the command line and use "netsh http flush logbuffer" to force the flushing of the logs to the files.
2. You can use ETW tracing to read the IIS Traces
3. You could use [Advanced Logging Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging) and leverage it to consume real-time events.